# How can I add files to java app in android so I can get it path?

Tags: java, android

I want to add files to java app in android so I'll know their path and can access them.
How can I do it? (It doesn't matter where they will be the most important is that I can access them and I'll know the relative path of the them)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file in your application by utilizing [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#CreatingResources). Depending on the type of the file, you add it in a different folder under res directory.

Comment: I want to add audio files. When I add them to res folder I get error on this folder. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

you can not add all formats of audio files. if i remeber correctly you can only add wave, mp3 and ogg files. maybe this was your problem? and additionnaly no one of this file should have the same name.

In wich res folder did you add the files?

Comment: I added it to raw folder.
How can I get its relative path?

Comment: You dont need a path for that. Just use R.raw.filename (filename without extension)